# maxByOrNull not returning the max value?

Tags: android, kotlin, max

I was just trying out 2 scenarios using `maxByOrNull`

```
"6,9".split(",").maxByOrNull { it }?.toInt()
```

and

```
"8,10".split(",").maxByOrNull { it }?.toInt()
```

The first statement returns 9, which is correct but the 2nd one returns 8.
I tried 10 and 11 then it's working. Seems like if we are comparing a single digit and another single digit it's working but not working if the number of digits are different.
[image]

And minByOrNull giving the max value, seems like a bug

[image]

Here is a link to kotlin playground  if someone wants to try it, https://pl.kotl.in/tVlAOBWq4

Comment: `split` will give you an array of strings. and `maxByOrNull` or `minByOrNull` is comparing the values as Strings, not as an Integer. So "8" comes after "10" in terms of Strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing strings - the string "9" and the string "10", which compares string character by character. If you want to compare them as integers, you should map each string to its integer value:

```
"8,10".split(",").map { it.toInt() }.maxByOrNull { it }?.toInt()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to accepted answer, you don't need to convert to int at last.

```
"8,10".split(",").map { it.toInt() }.maxByOrNull { it }
```

As the map would transform the `char` to `nt` and `maxByOrNull` would return value as `Int?`